# Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to push object into my array, but it showing the error

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected

In `Model-form.component.ts` file i have created dummy json array is test.

json array:

```
test: any[] = [{
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_name": "One",
        "cat_type": "One",
        "displayOrder": 1,
        "columns": [{
            "category": "One",
            "name": "one"
        }]
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "2",
        "cat_name": "SECURITY",
        "cat_type": "security",
        "displayOrder": 2,
        "columns": [{
            "category": "Two",
            "name": "two"
        }]
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "3",
        "cat_name": "COLLOBORATION",
        "cat_type": "colloboration",
        "displayOrder": 3,
        "columns": [{
            "category": "Three",
            "name": "three"
        }]
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "4",
        "cat_name": "NEW ARCHITECTURE",
        "cat_type": "newarch",
        "displayOrder": 4,
        "columns": [{
            "category": "Four",
            "name": "four"
        }]
    }
];
```

and i have tried to push object into the test array given below code

```
this.test.push({
    'cat_name': 'fdas',
    'cat_type': 'fsda'
});
```

but it's showing error. the [Code URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/model-driven-form-test-cql9w2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type script do not accept top level expressions inside a class.

Please move

```
this.test.push({
    'cat_name': 'fdas',
    'cat_type': 'fsda'
});
```

to inside a function and run the function.

Comment: Yes Praveen it's working when i changed from class to inside function. it's working like a charm

Comment: i need another clarification, whether it is possible to update json array where the cat_id": "4". please help me praveen

Comment: @ramu, happy to see it is working, you can try something like this,

var checkId = this.test.findIndex(el => el.cat_id === "4");
Where checkId is the index of an object in this.test array where cat_id === "4"

Now you can update the code using checkId,
this.test[checkId].push or this.test[checkId] = {//update your object here}.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

```
export class ModelFormComponent implements OnInit {
 langs: string[] = [
    'English',
    'French',
    'German',
    'Chinese',
    'Vietnamese',
  ];

test: any[] = [
{
"cat_id": "1",
"cat_name": "One",
"cat_type": "One",
"displayOrder":1,
"columns": [
{
"category": "One",
"name": "one"       
}
]
},
{
"cat_id": "2",
"cat_name": "SECURITY",
"cat_type": "security",
"displayOrder":2,
"columns": [
{
"category": "Two",
"name": "two"
}
]
},
{
"cat_id": "3",
"cat_name": "COLLOBORATION",
"cat_type": "colloboration",
"displayOrder":3,
"columns": [
{
"category": "Three",
"name": "three"
}
]
},
{
"cat_id": "4",
"cat_name": "NEW ARCHITECTURE",
"cat_type": "newarch",
"displayOrder":4,
"columns": [
{
"category": "Four",
"name": "four"
}
]
}
];




this.test.push({
    'cat_name': 'fdas',
    'cat_type': 'fsda'
});
```

**You cannot push to an array inside of class in Angular 5, a class is merely a representation of properties**.

In order for this to work you have to choices:

1): Use it inside a method in your component scope:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }),
      email: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*")
      ]),
      password: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8)
      ]),
      language: new FormControl()
    });
        this.test.push({
    'cat_name': 'fdas',
    'cat_type': 'fsda'
});
```

}

2): Use it as an imported class and push the items into the array:

```
    import { Component, OnInit,NgModule, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
    import { myClass } from './models/myClass';
    import {ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        FormGroup,
        FormControl,
        Validators,
        FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'model-form',
      templateUrl: './model-form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./model-form.component.css']
    })
    export class ModelFormComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private MyClass: myClass) {
}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.MyClass.test.push({
    'cat_name': 'fdas',
    'cat_type': 'fsda'
});
}
```